# iphone UILocalNotification with custom uiview

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios9, uilocalnotification

[image]

I am new ios developer coding with Objective C, where I am working on project where development requires local notification as shown in image with buttons or view or progress view

Please help !

Thanking your Support

Comment: You want to display this view in notification tray or inside your app?

Comment: DISPLAY TO NOTIFICATION TRAY